# Best Labview IPC

Tags: c, ipc, labview

I need to make labview communicate with a C/C++ application. Both the applications run on the same machine. What is the IPC mechanism with lower overhead and highest speed available in LabView?

Answer (score 3):

TCP, UDP, ActiveX, DDE, file transactions, or perhaps just directly calling a dll are the solutions that come to mind.

First I'd just call a dll if you can manage with that.  Assuming you're tied in to using two separate applications then:

I'd use TCP or UDP.  File transactions are clunky but easy to implement, DDE is older but might be viable (I'd recommend against it).

[Basic TCP/IP in Labview](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/2710/en)

[TCP/IP and UDP in Labview](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361J-01/lvconcepts/using_labview_with_tcp_ip_and_udp/#UDP_Multicast)

[Calling a dll from Labview](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/DCB90714981A1F148625731E00797C33)

Answer (score 2):

Have you investigated straight up TCP or UDP?

It'll make it easy if you ever need to separate the applications onto different machines later on down the road.  Implementation is pretty straight forward too, although it may not be the fastest throughput.

What speeds are we talking about here?

Comment: My idea was to have a kind of ranking as answer.

Answer (score 1):

NI has provided a thorough document explaining that: [Using External Code in LabVIEW [pdf]](http://www.ni.com/pdf/manuals/370109a.pdf). In brief, you can use:

1. Shared Libraries (on windows they are called DLLs). According to the above document, any
   language can be used to write DLLs as long as the DLLs can be called
   using one of the calling conventions LabVIEW supports, either
   stdcall or C."
2. Code Interface Node (CIN), which is a block diagram node that links C/C++ source 
   code to LabVIEW.
3. .NET technology.

Note that "Shared Libraries" and "Code Interface Node" are supported on Windows, Max OS X, Linux and Solaris.